# Git diff3 file "deleted by us"

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

On regular merges, `merge.conflictstyle diff3` shows me a helpful

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
  changes on HEAD
||||||| merged common ancestors
  base
|||||||
  changes on branchB
>>>>>>> branchB
```

How can I show this diff for files "deleted by us" on a merge conflict?

I'm aware that one of the blocks will be empty as "we" don't have anything in that file on "our" side, but I want to see what changed in "their" branch.

Example of what I'd like to see:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
||||||| merged common ancestors
  base
|||||||
  changes on branchB
>>>>>>> branchB
```

Note `<<<<<<< HEAD` and `||||||| merged common ancestors` is next to each other since the file contents are empty at `HEAD`.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer somehow? I am also very curious about a solution here.